# Rails: Can not save on DB during rspec features test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

---

I'm using rspec to perform feature tests and I can't save the user in the DB before the log in.
I'm using factory girl to build the object.
fixture are saved in db at the beginning of the test but are not deleted at the end.(maybe because the test fail. I don't know)

So I can not save the user before clicking on logIn and I get this errror message

--
DEPRECATION WARNING: an empty resource was given to Devise::Strategies::DatabaseAuthenticatable#validate. Please ensure the resource is not nil. (called from set_required_vars at app/controllers/application_controller.rb:43)

spec/features/login_to_mainpage_spec.rb (no error are rescued)

```
require "rails_helper"

feature 'Navigating to homepage' do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:login_page) { MainLoginPage.new }

  scenario "login" do
    login_page.visit_page.login(user)
    sleep(20)
  end
end
```

A simple page object: spec/features/pages_objects/main_login_page.rb

```
class MainLoginPage
  include Capybara::DSL

  def login(user)
    fill_in 'email', with: user.email
    fill_in 'password', with: "password"
    click_on 'logIn'
  end

  def visit_page
    visit '/'
    self
  end
end
```

my rails_helper

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
require "selenium-webdriver"
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/features/page_objects/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  config.before :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end
  config.after :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox)
end
```

in spec helper:

```
require 'simplecov'
require 'factory_girl'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'


ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
RSpec.configure do |config|
  include ActionDispatch::TestProcess
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
  config.disable_monkey_patching!

  if config.files_to_run.one?
    config.default_formatter = 'doc'
  end

  config.profile_examples = 10

  config.order = :random

  Kernel.srand config.seed
end
```

**EDIT 1**

I switch "gem 'factory_girl'" to "gem 'factory_girl_rails'"

and add this to application.rb

```
config.generators do
|g|
  g.test_framework :rspec,
                   :fixtures => true,
                   :view_specs => false,
                   :helper_specs => false,
                   :routing_specs => false,
                   :controller_specs => true,
                   :request_specs => true
  g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, :dir => "spec/factories"
end
```

I still can not save the user in DB.
Everything pass but I put some sleep(10) in by code to refresh my DB and see te records and user is never saved

**EDIT 3**

My problem is actually very simple. FactoryGirl.create never save the data in DB if I put in my rails_helper:

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

or

```
config.before :each do
 DatabaseCleaner.start
end
config.after :each do
 DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

/spec/factories

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user  do
    email 'pierre@tralala.com'
    password 'password'
    password_confirmation 'password'
end
```

/spec/support/factory_girl.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

spec/features/login_to_mainpage_spec.rb

```
let(:user) { create(:user) }
scenario "login" do
  login_page.visit_page.login(create(:user))
  sleep(5)
end
```

User will not be saved because of the config I cited before.
I need to have data reseted between tests.

**EDIT 4**

If I'm using the console

```
RAILS_ENV=test rails c
FactoryGirl.create(:user) it is saved in db.
```

I don't understand why it does not work in my tests.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `let!` to create your user. 
From the [rSpec documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let):

> Note that let is lazy-evaluated: it is not evaluated until the first time
>   the method it defines is invoked. You can use let! to force the method's
>   invocation before each example.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you are using FactoryGirl but I do not see this in your test. To create my Users with FactoryGirl I always do something like this:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:user, password: 'test', password_confirmation: 'test', name: 'test')
```

If setup correctly in your Factory you can just write:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:user)
```

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna try this

Comment: I did a lot of tweak and I still have te problem.
I switch "factory_girl" gem for "factory_girl_rails" gem but the factory still does not save the user in DB

Comment: Are you sure that the user is not saved to the DB or might it be that your login fails for another reason. 
You could also try to remove your DataBaseCleaner in your rails_helper to see if there is a problem with this gem.

Comment: Yes you are right. now it works BUT all my unit tests are failing because they where using DatabaseCleaner.
-> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email has already been taken.

how can I make everything work? Unit test + feature test

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem with the unique fields FactoryGirl provides you sequences:

```
sequence :email do |n|
    "person#{n}@example.com"
end

factory :user do
    email { generate(:email }
end
```

This will start with "person1@example.com" and add 1 to the number each time FactoryGirl.create(:user) is called.